# Angular Router usehash: navigate is not preserve the url before the hastag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I have the following URL:

```
https://localhost:4200/example/#/
```

When I navigate no another angular route like the following example shows, the `/example` is erased from the URL. The resulting URL is `https://localhost:4200/#/firstSegment/secondSegment` instead of `https://localhost:4200/example/#/firstSegment/secondSegment`

```
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
....

navigate() {
    this.router.navigate([`/firstSegment/secondSegment`]);
}
```

There is a way that I could preserve the URL part before the `#` each time I perform the navigation?

Follows my router config:

```
@NgModule({
   .....
   imports: [
      .....
      RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {
        enableTracing: false, // <-- debugging purposes only
        useHash: true,
        initialNavigation: false
      }
     .....
   ]

})
```

Comment: Which the angular version?

Comment: @RafaelPizao Angular 8.

Comment: Since Angular 6.1 it is possible to scroll the page using fragments. Do you use page scrolling or is 'second segment' a new route?

Comment: @RafaelPizao The first part I want to maint always. The second part represents the angular rote define in appRoutes that will load a given angular component. The first part is information that is important for running the application.

Comment: Set <base href="/example">  in your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

For the default route, you need to set the prefix to ***angular.json***

```
...
"projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "prefix": "example",
    ...
}
...
```

More details
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config